# change hints accept key in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code

i new in VS code i want to change hint accept key from "Enter" to "space" and "."

and of course this keys works in normal edit and only works when hint bar is open

i tried something like this on keybinding.json

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to overwrite the defaults
[
      {
          "key": "space",
          "command": "repl.action.acceptInput",
          "when": "parameterHintsVisible"
      }
]
```

but it doesn't work , where i going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the command you are looking for is `acceptSelectedSuggestionOnEnter`:

```
{
    "key": "space",
    "command": "acceptSelectedSuggestionOnEnter",
    "when": "acceptSuggestionOnEnter && editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetVisible"
}
```

Comment: yes this is what i want. thanks but now i must press "." twice one for accept suggestion another for typing it for code parts how can make it ones? :D